# Best approach to handle a possible deadlock with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, database-deadlocks

So, I recently discovered the existence of [deadlocks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html). Despite I never had one, I understand this can be a problem outside the testing enviroment with lots of users accessing at the same time.

I learnt some tips to make it happen *less* but not never, so I am concerned about proper handling this. So, let's say we are accessing the database through JDBC.

I didn't find any reference to the deadlock handling neither in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html) nor the [official examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) as they just rollback (or print and exception if not possible):

> ```
> } catch (SQLException e ) {
>         JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
>         if (con != null) {
>             try {
>                 System.err.print("Transaction is being rolled back");
>                 con.rollback();
>             } catch(SQLException excep) {
>                 JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(excep);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

As I understood reading the documentation,  if the `executeUpdate()` method finds a deadlock it doesn't retry again in any way.

Searching different solutions I found [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936001/8719655), which **wraps the whole thing into a loop with a counter and a sleep between each try**.

So, my quoestions here are:

1. Do JDBC handle in any way deadlocks beyond throwing an exception? Any library in any language does (at least optionally) retry the query?
2. How would you handle this on a deadblock-sensitive scenario with a JDBC implementation?
3. Do you prevent this in your custom database access methods? Also, do you have them or do you just use the default lines each time you access the database?
4. Why doesn't the database engine restart the victim query when the needed rows get unlocked?

EDIT: I found this on [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html):

> Always be prepared to re-issue a transaction if it fails due to deadlock. Deadlocks are not dangerous. Just try again.

Which suggests to handle it on the application code.

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. No, it does not because it cannot. Deadlock is an error that needs handling in the business logic. 2. There is no JDBC-specific solution. Why? Because handling a deadlock depends on your business logic, so there is no one-size-fits-all approach to handling deadlocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While deadlock mitigation may have some value, in a well-designed system deadlocks should be exceptionally rare. You mentioned learning some tips on how to avoid them, but here is my own list:

- In many systems, there are top-level objects/entities that you always lock first before updating their child tables. For example, an order processing system might have many different tables to hold the data, but you would always try to lock the top-level order entity first.
- More generally, if all code accessing the database always locks entities in the same order, then deadlocks won't happen. (For example, if one connection locks rows from tables A and C in that order, and another locks A, B and C in order, no deadlock can occur no matter what the timing is for those locks.)
- Systems can also be designed to eliminate most locking. For example, if data
  is appended rather than edited, then no lock is needed.
- In a NoSQL database, all the related data is typically held in a single object. Locking is not needed and might not even be supported by the database.

If you allow users ad-hoc write access to the database then of course you can't control the factors that lead to deadlock. But I've never seen a serious system that allowed it.

So rather than worrying about responding to deadlocks, all your energies should be spent on avoiding them entirely. When you see a deadlock, you find the bug in your system that allowed it to happen.

Comment: Could a deadlock happen inside the same table with lots of masive-row updates running at the same time? Or do the locking work always in the same direction, preventing this happening whithin a unique table?

Comment: It could happen simply by connection 1 locking row A then B, and connection 2 locking row B then A. But in actual business scenarios it can almost always be avoided because updates aren't random- the rows are related in a business sense, and that often means a higher level object can be locked first. If not, you could still avoid it by always locking in sorted key order (assuming you have all the keys needing to be locked up front.)

Comment: Re-reading your comment, I missed that you were talking about massive row updates, presumable single-statement updates. It's a good question! I would guess that some or most databases use a consistent order when performing multi-row updates, to avoid deadlocks. Or they might lock entire pages or the table itself. I'm not sure- it hasn't come up. Either I'm locking a parent object first, or it's a one-time migration/conversion scenario.

Comment: @Bampfer you forget on your *deadlock prevention* list: *let only one user at a time update the database..;)*

Comment: Interesting approach, MB. Why stop at locking a single row, page, or table? Just lock the whole database! :-)

Comment: @MarmiteBomber The next step of that is to build your own database engine.

Comment: My point was, that it is of course meaningful to try to limit the possibility of deadlock with *organisation* rules, but without a *brute force* you gen never get rid of them completely. On the other side @Carlos a deadlock exception is not really much different than an exception after update failing with version conflict, so IMO no extra handling is required.